# javascript method writing patterns

Tags: javascript, gulp

This is regarding javascript programming pattern. while working with the gulp, I came across 2 different type of function calling pattern and this is really confusing so someone clarifies Is both functions are doing the same job?

```
  gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'), 
    function(event) {
        if(event.type === 'changed') {
          callAMethod();
        } else {
          callBMethod();
        }
  });
```

in above method, we can write if else condition

but in this pattern

```
 gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'))
 .on('change', callAMethod);
```

If yes then please suggest some links Where I can read about it and which is the better way to handle the errors? also, where do we write else part in the later method style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both different.

The first one is a callback to the `gulp.watch` method and it gets *all* the events that the watcher produces

The second one does not provide a callback, instead it *subscribes* to one event (change) produced.

---

The watch method returns a [`Gaze`](https://github.com/shama/gaze) object and to handle errors, subscribe to the `error` event:

```
watcher.on('error', function(error) {
  // Handle error here
});
```

[Gulp4](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md) which is still in alpha stage uses [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar). To watch for errors, it's exactly the same as the above:

```
watcher.on('error', error => log(`Watcher error: ${error}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

These functions are different.

Gulp uses a utility named [glob-watcher](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-watcher) for handling file changes and the first one is a callback called by glob-watcher.

The second one is a raw event from Event Emitter (NodeJS Emitter or [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)) instance.

Some events from EventEmmiter propagate to glob-watcher callback - for example, "change", so it may look the same on the first look.

For handling errors, I recommend having a look at gulp-plumber plugin.